# Form submits correctly in Chrome/FF, but fails altogether in IE/Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, safari

I have a form with a css submit button.    When a the submit button is clicked, i call a function that executes:

```
document.forms["request"].onsubmit();
```

What should happen, then, is that the onsubmit method ought to be triggered.  This works properly in Chrome/FF, but for some reason IE/Safari will bypass the onsubmit function and simply add the parameter "address=" onto the url as if it were submitting the form and ignoring the onsubmit function.  Heres the code for the form:

```
      <form id="request" method="get" onsubmit="addLocation(this.address.value); return false;">
        <br>
        <label style="position:relative;left:5px;" for="address">Enter an intersection or address:
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input style="height:35px; width:300px;position:relative;bottom:1px;left:10px;" id="address" name="address" class="required address"/>
        <a style="float:right;right:120px;position:relative;" class="button" onclick="submit();">
          <span>Submit Request
          </span>
        </a>
      </form>
```

and what follows are some relevant js functions:

```
function addLocation(address) {
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLocations(address, function (point) {
            if (!point) {
                alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
                if (point.Placemark[0].address != submittedString) {
                    submittedString = point.Placemark[0].address;
                    addRow(point.Placemark[0].address);
                    req = "addrequest?truck=" + "coolhaus&address=" + point.Placemark[0].address;
                    alert(req);
                    addRequest(req);
                    request.onreadystatechange = function () {}
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function addRequest(req) {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("XMLHttpRequest error: " + e);
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", req, true);
    request.send(null);
    return request;
}
```

You can test the form here:

http://la.truxmap.com/request?id=grillmastersla

Thanks so much!

Comment: It's odd that Chrome and Safari, being built on the same engine, would behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your function "submit", there is already a method in the form with that name, so it can conflict with that.

It's the `submit` method that you can call to submit the form, not the `onsubmit` event. So, your code to post the form should be:

```
document.forms["request"].submit();
```